# Shopify Webhook not sending to controller

Tags: ruby, api, shopify

Thru the Shopify API I can create webhooks great. I've created ones that point to RequestBin just fine, the data that is sent to RequestBin is perfect. But when I turn it towards my own controllers nothing happens. I have a binding.pry in my controller to catch anything that comes in, and nothing ever comes in. Not sure why??

Here is me creating the hook with the ShopifyAPI gem:

```
webhook = ShopifyAPI::Webhook.create(:topic => "carts/update", 
:format => "json",:address => "https://dyno-shipping-trimakas.c9users.io
/webhook/cart_callback/")
```

And then here it is verified when I list the webhooks:

```
{"id"=>226014599,
"address"=>
"https://dyno-shipping-trimakas.c9users.io/webhook/cart_callback/",
"topic"=>"carts/create",
"created_at"=>"2016-02-24T17:20:02-05:00",
"updated_at"=>"2016-02-24T17:20:02-05:00",
"format"=>"json",
"fields"=>[],
"metafield_namespaces"=>[]}
```

This is my controller:

```
class WebHookController < ApplicationController
skip_before_action :verify_authenticity_token, only: [:cart_callback] 
  def cart_callback 
    binding.pry
    x = params
    pp x
  end
end
```

Then finally this is my route:

```
scope '/webhook', :controller => :webhook do
  post :cart_callback
end
```

Not sure where I went astray??

Comment: Everything seems fine in your controller and webhook api call. Do you think it's your route that might be having the issue? I mean, can you call the route through an internal get or post?

Another issue could be your topic. Could you try a different on?

Comment: I ended up switching the format of the webhook to XML from JSON, and it worked.. I have no idea why.. I thought my controller should respond to either, but it didn't!

Comment: @HussienK its not working again.. wow.. I have no idea what's happening.. I can curl the URL and it will show the HTML, I can post to it using HTTParty but no response.. no clue what I'm doing wrong